# Azure-hosted WCF service results in error 400

Tags: jquery, wcf, web-services, azure, get

This should be enough. If I go to `site/core.svc/dowork` I get a 400 error.

The results are the same on an .ajax call. Where did I go wrong?

I'm trying to make this web accessible. I'm going to add methods down the line to deal with state management based on browser events.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Icore
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string DoWork();
}

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class core : Icore
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
  <service name="Fusion.core" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" >
    <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
    <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
    <endpoint contract="Fusion.Icore" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding" address="" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: And what config does your **client** use?

Comment: I'm trying to make it web accessable. I'll add that to the description.

Comment: In that case - you're using the **wrong** binding - if you want "web-accessible" (as in callable from a browser), you must use the `webHttpBinding` (not `wsHttpBinding` or `basicHttpBinding`)

Comment: Excellent, I'll make some tweaks and try again. If it works, submit as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Alright, getting a new error now. Go ahead and submit an answer, I'm going to post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, wanting to make your service *web accessible* (callable from a regular browser), you need to use the REST approach (not SOAP).

For that, you're using the wrong binding; you need to use the `webHttpBinding` (and not `wsHttpBinding` or `basicHttpBinding`, which are SOAP binding that aren't callable from just a browser - you need a SOAP client software)